# Ruby On Rails - Mask heroku domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, deployment, heroku, dns

I have a RoR3 server deployed to Heroku (With some webservices).
I have a domain www.domain.com 
What I want to do is that www.domain.com/api points directly to my Heroku url.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing a domain to heroku is [simple with the custom domains add-on](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).  However, pointing just an /api route to Heroku is problematic as DNS does not work that way.

Ideally you want to look at something like api.domain.com if you're looking to host www.domain.com elsewhere.